# jQuery - Set value AND text of input

Tags: jquery, input

I have a form and I am auto-populating a price field using an API. What I would like to do is set the value of the input(what gets submitted) to the number, but in the actual input field I want it to display in price format.

```js
$(function() {
  var price = 3.25;
  $('input').val(price);
  $('input').text('$' + price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="price" type="text" />
```

In the above an example, how would I make it so that the value that gets submitted is just the raw number `3.25` but it displays as `$3.25` in the actual input field?

Comment: You can't since the `text()` function doesn't apply to inputs. Why not just put a `$` in front of the text field like `$<input id="price" type="text" />`?

Comment: In my experience, the common approach to this sort of thing is to put just the numerical part in a span or something with an identifier on it, and the $ appears before that element.  Then all your logic does is set the span.  But to the user it looks like the $ belongs to the amount.

Comment: Bootstrap, and possibly other libraries, also have nice little ways of attaching the $ to an input so it's not a part of the value, but doesn't look trashy.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrapped your input in a `<span>`, you could put some styling on it to make the input look like it has a preceding `$` without affecting its `value`. Using this method, you'd simply just need to wrap your input in `<span class="currency"></span>` and the rest will be taken care of via CSS.

---

**Plain** - Absolutely positions a pseudo-element into a left-padded input

```js
var price = 3.25;
$('#price').val(price);
```

```css
.currency {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.currency::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '$';
  left: 3px;
  top: 0;
}

.currency input[type=text] {
  padding-left: 9px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="currency"><input type="text" id="price" /></span>
```

---

**"Bootstrap Style"** - Create a pseudo-element "indicator" to the left of the input

```js
var price = 3.25;
$('#price').val(price);
```

```css
.currency {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.currency::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '$';
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #efefef;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.currency > input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="currency"><input type="text" id="price" /></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the '$' inside the textbox?

You can better add '$' in the html itself as a label since always its a price field.

```
<lable>$</label><input id="price" type="text" />
```